# WinRT StaticResource from ViewModel in referenced Assembly

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am in the process of porting one of our iOS applications to Windows 8/8.1. Using the MVVM design pattern I have created a ViewModel for one of the Pages to use. Similar to our WebApp the Windows application separates the layers by grouping relevant objects in Class Libraries. There is a Business/Model Layer (I will reference this as App.BLL) and a Data Access Layer (I will reference this as App.Data).

App references App.BLL, and App.BLL references App.Data. App.BLL contains a namespace called Items, which contains a Class ItemsViewModel. ItemsViewModel contains a ObservableCollection Items. When ItemsViewModels' constructor is called, it sets Items by calling a method contained in App.Data (List LoadItems()).

The issue I have been pulling my hair out over is, the designer is displaying an error on  as seen below.

"Error 3 Type universe cannot resolve assembly: App.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null."

I imagine this is due to App.BLL having a reference to App.Data, where App does not reference App.Data. I have also tried explicitly defining the assembly of xmlns:model (xmlns:model="using:App.BLL.Items;assembly=App.BLL").

This only leads to a separate error while in the designer only.

Error 7 Assembly 'App.BLL' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference. Also, verify that your project and all referenced assemblies have been built.

If the designer is closed the first error mentioned is gone (when defining the assembly), and is replaced by:

Error 6 Unknown type 'ItemsViewModel' in XML namespace 'using:App.BLL.Products;assembly=App.BLL'

However, it does exist.

```cs
namespace App.BLL.Items
{
    public class ItemsViewModel : IItemInterface
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        public ItemsViewModel()
        {
            Items = Item.GetItems();
        }

        private Item _selectedItem;
        public Item SelectedItem
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedItem;
            }
            set
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                OnItemSelected(_selectedItem);
            }
        }
        private RelayCommand<Item> _itemSelected;
        public RelayCommand<Item> ItemSelected
        {
            get
            {
                return _itemSelected ??
                    (_itemSelected = new RelayCommand<Item>(item =>
                    {
                        SelectedItem = item;
                        //Notify Item Selected
                    }));
            }
        }
        public event ItemSelectedEventHandler ItemSelectedChanged;
        protected virtual void OnItemSelected(Item selectedItem)
        {
            ItemSelectedChanged(this, new ItemChangedEventArgs(selectedItem));
        }
    }
}
```

At this point I could not care less about the designer error's, as they go away while it is closed so it seems that at Runtime it would work. However with Error 6 above I can not compile.

```
<Page
    x:Class="App.ItemsPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:model="using:App.BLL.Items"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <model:ItemsViewModel x:Key="ItemSource" />
    </Page.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemSource}}" />
</Page>
```

I have looked around the web all day before asking a question here, I hope I provided everything needed to help in finding a solution.

Edit: I can't for the life of me get this formatted correctly. I will keep working on it, but if someone could edit that would be ok also.

Comment: Are the references added by referencing the solution, or by pointing to the dlls?

Comment: Also, make sure your other projects are all the same type (I.e. PCL's targeting windows 8 (or 8.1), or Library projects targeting the same version as the UI project)

Comment: Great question, and an oversight I did not think of including. They are referenced via the solution. All projects are 8.1.

Comment: When you build the project do all 3 dll's exist in the debug folder? If not ensure your build config is configured correctly.

Comment: Yes if I remove the line "<model:ItemsViewModel x:Key="ItemSource" />" so that the solution compiles all dll's exist in "bin/x86/Debug".

Comment: Why x86, and not anycpu? Are You specifically targeting a CPU for any reason?

Comment: x86 due to SQLite-net. That library does not allow Any CPU, you must choose ARM/x86/x64.

Comment: On the view (in code behind) can you set the this.DataContext to your model.ItemsViewModel and see if that works.

Comment: Yes, that does work (it was how the project was configured before moving to the ViewModel design). I was just trying to keep the code behind as clean as possible by taking advantage of this.